# Structuring a Visual Studio C++ solution with multiple top-level application projects sharing dependencies

Tags: c++, visual-studio, build

I've got a C++ source base with 2 top-level applications (A,B) and two shared library projects (C,D). C is used by both A and B while D is only used by B.

When I build, I end up with a single build output folder containing

```
A.exe
B.exe
C.dll
D.dll
```

This works, but I really wish I could have two folders:

```
A's FOLDER:
A.exe
C.dll

B's FOLDER:
B.exe
C.dll
D.dll
```

What's the best way to pull this off? In practice I've got more application-level projects and more dependent dlls, so the most efficient way from a developer workflow standpoint is what I'm looking for.

Ideas so far, none of which I'm crazy about:

1. Give each project its own output directory, and use build events on the application projects to copy in the contents of the output directories for the dependent dll projects. Drawback here is redundancy with the project references themselves.

   Just let everything stay in a single output directory and make it a distribution problem. Drawback here is the knowledge of what belongs to who lives in two different places.

Comment: Assuming each program and DLL is its own project in a single workspace, then it's not that hard to tell each project to write the final executable/DLL into a specific directory. The problem is C.dll which needs to be written to two places. AFAIK Visual Studio have the possibility to run commands as a post-build action, in which case you can copy C.dll into the two destination directories.

Comment: If you use [project references](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/47w1hdab.aspx), you can enable the "Copy Local" option on your dependencies (I think it's "True" by default). Then set the output folder for each EXE project to its own folder. Visual Studio should copy each dependency from the DLL projects' intermediate directory into the respective EXE's directory like in your latter example.

Comment: How the build environment is structured is not very important. More important is the target environment where the app is installed. I wouldn't complicate things unnecessarily. Furthermore, if the executables are part of the same software package, then they are normally installed in the same folder anyway.

Comment: @BretKuhns - unfortunately CopyLocal does nothing in the unmanaged C++ world. It does exactly what you said for C# projects, making it easy to have nice self-contained output folders for each application; but no such functionality is present for old-fashioned C++ projects (even though the property "CopyLocal" is still present).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg - that's basically option 1